Retrieve data from now to last hour of modified time in SOQL
SELECT Id, Name, Quote_Name_DISPLAY__c, SBQQ__Account__r.Name, Agency__r.name, 
       Agency__r.Customer_Number__c, SBQQ__Status__c, Customer_Number__c,
       LastModifiedDate 
   FROM SBQQ__Quote__c 
   WHERE SBQQ__Status__c IN ('Approved', 'Accepted', 'Superceded') and 
        LastModifiedDate = TODAY AND HOUR_IN_DAY(LastModifiedDate) >1 

For the above SOQL query, I am trying to retrieve data from the last modified date, which is one hour from now. This means if i am querying data at 9:00 AM and would like to retrieve data from 9:00 AM to 8:00 AM.

N.B. superceded is spelled superseded in case you have a chance to correct this before deployment

HOUR_IN_DAY returns a number representing the hour in the day for a Datetime field, i.e. if LastModifiedDate is 2024-09-16T23:52:46Z, HOUR_IN_DAY(LastModifiedDate) returns 23
Therefore it isn't the right function for your use case.
You could leverage Datetime.addHours() providing -1 as input to get the Datetime you need, then bind that variable in the SOQL:
Datetime oneHourAgo = System.now().addHours(-1);
List<SBQQ__Quote__c> = [
    SELECT Name, Quote_Name_DISPLAY__c, SBQQ__Account__r.Name, Agency__r.name, Agency__r.Customer_Number__c, SBQQ__Status__c, Customer_Number__c, LastModifiedDate
    FROM SBQQ__Quote__c
    WHERE SBQQ__Status__c IN ('Approved', 'Accepted', 'Superceded') 
          AND LastModifiedDate >= :oneHourAgo 
];

Running this code you'll retrieve every record modified in the last hour.
